# How to insert default data to columns which depend on another column?

Tags: mysql, database

As the table above, every problem has its own status, but only when `status_id = 3` (`status=finished`), `date_completed` has value, otherwise, `date_completed` should be default `NULL`.

How to do that?

[image]

I mean if there are many rows which status_id is not 3, so the column date_completed should be NULL. I don't want to insert 'NULL' one by one, I want insert it when status_id is not 3.
But it seems I can't separate the status and date_completed to another table...

Comment: Your question is unintelligible, and shows no effort.

Comment: uh..sorry, I wrote a wrong title...

Comment: When inserting data, just don't specify any attribute you don't want to set. You may want to provide a default value for such attributes in the table definition, _if_ different from `NULL`/the default value for the attribute type (as well as `NOT NULL` constraints for attributes that _must_ be provided).

Comment: You could create a stored procedure using which you can enter data into that table. Stored procedure would have the logic to check the status and then populate the date when the correct status is available. The other option is to create a trigger with similar business logic. Can you try one of those methods and report back if there are issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use check constraint something like

alter table tab_name
add constraint check_date CHECK(case when (status_id ! = 3 AND status != finished)
                                then NULL else date_completed  end = date_completed );